# When Matlis duality is isomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $(R,\mathfrak m, k)$ be a Noetherian, complete, local ring. Let $E$ be an injective hull of $k$. difine for every $R$-module $M$
$$\mu_M:M\to Hom_R(Hom_R(M,E),E)$$
is natural $R$ homomorphis, such that $\mu_M(x)(f)=f(x)$ , $x\in M$ and $f\in Hom(M,E)$.
suppose $M$ is an $R$-module and has noetherian submodule $N$ such that $\frac{M}{N}$ is an artinian $R$-module.I want to show that $\mu_M$ is isomorphism.
I known that $\mu_M$ is always one one but I dont know how to show that is it onto? maybe the commutative diagram is helpful.
$$\begin{array}
A0 & {\longrightarrow} & N \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} & M \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & \frac{M}{N} & {\longrightarrow} & 0 \\
 & & \downarrow{h} & \downarrow{h'}&  \downarrow{h''}\\
0 & {\longrightarrow} & N^{**} \stackrel{f^{**}}{\longrightarrow} & M^{**} \stackrel{g^{**}}{\longrightarrow} & \frac{M}{N}^{**} & {\longrightarrow} & 0
\end{array}\\
$$
$N^{**}=Hom_R(Hom_R(N,E),E)$

Any hint or solution would be helpful.

Thank You

Comment: It seems that $h$ and $h^{''}$  are isomorphisms and by using the five lemma $h'$ is an isomorphism.